# Using asyn await in foreach loop

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Is it incorrect to use asyc await in a foreach loop? I get a WebException, The request was canceled.

The following is just a outline of the code I’m working on. Please let me know if this is not clear.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://xxx.xxx.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("customers/xxxx/xxx/documents", requestMessage);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var returnValue = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ResponseMessage>();

        var hasDocuments = returnValue.Result.SearchResults.Any();

        if (hasDocuments)
        {
            // HTTP GET
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

            returnValue.Result.SearchResults.ForEach(async d =>
            {
                response = await client.GetAsync(d.Self + ".pdf");
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using async/await in a `foreach` loop, you are using async/await with [`List<T>.ForEach(Action<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx). Because `ForEach` only accepts `Action<T>` (void return type) your `ForEach(async d => { ... }` is being processed as a `async void` function because that is the only way for it to be passed in as a `Action<T>`. This makes ForEach not wait for the previous item to finish before moving to the next item and that is what causes your error.

Use a normal `foreach` instead of the `List<T>.ForEach` method and it should work fine.

```
    if (hasDocuments)
    {
        // HTTP GET
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

        foreach (var d in returnValue.Result.SearchResults)
        {
            response = await client.GetAsync(d.Self + ".pdf");  
        };
    }
```

The only time you are allowed to use `async d => ...` is when the function you are passing in to takes in a `Func<T,Task>` (See [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx) as an example).